# use custom service with angular service in another service - angular2

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-services

I have two services which one of them(Logger) is going to be used by another(SettingService), I have already searched a lot and see other questions and answers to this problem but no luck, I've already read this document [angualr.io/When the service needs a service](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#when-the-service-needs-a-service)

here is the code for two services

**Logger** as a service

```
@Injectable()
export class Logger {

    public logs: string[] = [];
    //do stuffs
}
```

**SettingService**

```
@Injectable()
export class SettingService
{   
    private url = '/setting';
    private headers = new Headers({ 'content-type': 'application/json' });

    constructor(private http: Http,private logger: Logger) { } //problem is here
    //do stuffs   
}
```

the `settingService` is using both `http` and `logger`, I have a  component `app.component` which uses `settingService`, here is my `app.component` and `app.module`

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private settingService: SettingService) { }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
    @NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  providers:    [Logger, SettingService],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

but unfortunately I get the error which says : 
`(SystemJS) Can't resolve all parameters for SettingService: ([object Object], ?).Error: Can't resolve all parameters for SettingService: ([object Object], ?)` 
what is wrong??

this is [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/viZViLIvbSpSETqumOeM), that's not working!

Comment: @ParidOkht this may sound silly but can you try providing it in appcomponent instead of appmodule once . I know you want services to be singleton but just try once

Comment: also if possible can you create a small plunker to demonstarte the issues as the code listed here is fine , there must be something else

Comment: @RahulSingh I tried providing it in `app.component`, no luck

Comment: actually it works for me but i use webpack cli

Comment: @Vega how should I find that?

Comment: @RahulSingh I add a `plunker` at the end, but unfortunately it is not working for some other reason I think,

Comment: Here's a fixed plunk https://plnkr.co/edit/zDlIGzU4GlhHhYF9Ig5z?p=info . It throws `Cannot read property 'logger' of undefined` which means that DI went ok. The question cannot be answered because the problem cannot be replicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the order of import services into AppModule or try to use forwardRef() in settingService, such as constructor(private http: Http, @Inject(forwardRef(() => Logger)) private logger: Logger)

Comment: yes you were right, but I saw your answer late,the problem was about import ordering of my service in `app.module.ts`, I explained it in one answer. thanks

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is providing the logger in the bootstrap providers like this

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ 
    provide(Logger, {useClass: Logger},
    ....) 
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

the error was **ERORR:  Can't resolve all parameters for Custom Service: ([object Object], ?)**

I am using a `index.ts` file  under services folder to export my services and then I import that index file in `app.module.ts`, the order of exporting in `index.ts` which comes to importing in `app.module` is **important**. it should be from least dependency to most dependency 
as my experience please be careful about these bellow thing:

1. Avoid Circular Dependency
2. Be Careful about register ordering of services in app.module provider
3. Be careful about the import ordering of services in `app.module.ts`, which are dependent to each other, It must be ordered form low dependency to high dependency, otherwise you will get error  injecting a service to another service. so, If you are using `index.ts` and export all your services there and then import `index.ts` in your `app.module.ts` you must be careful about the export ordering of your classes in `index.ts`